# When did iota devs adopt ternary over binary?

Tags: legacy-protocol, ternary

I read the Nov 30 posting , which was great. Just not clear when project became so aligned to ternary.

Comment: When isn't the same as why

Comment: Indeed I retracted my duplicate vote.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping this forum wud be the antithesis of Slack.  Good data point

Comment: Can you please add a link to that "Nov 30 posting" to your question via [edit]?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about the legacy-network and it is a good idea to keep only Shimmer/ShimmerEVM and latest IOTA Chrysalis questions

Answer (score 1):

Ternary is in the scope from day one. In fact cfb is working on this since many years. Here is a quote from cfb on the nxt forum (from 2014) :

> We can count from the 30th of April 2014 when the name "Jinn" came to my mind - https://nxtforum.org/pub-crawl/rfc-project-'jinn'-(processor)/msg14306/#msg14306...
>
> Or from the summer of 2012 when I wrote the ancestor of Jinn emulator (a framework called "Black Heart")...
>
> Or from the autumn of 2010 when I rewrote server code from C to Java (for MMORPG "Apocatastasis")...
>
> Or from the autumn of 2004 when I wrote first lines for the server part of my MMORTS (forgot its name)...
>
> There is no a moment when I started working on Jinn.

[Source](https://nxtforum.org/news-and-announcements/(ann)-jinn/40/)